# Java JNI memory management

Tags: java, c++, memory-management, java-native-interface, embedded

I want to wrap a C++ library using the Java Native Interface. I wonder how memory management can be done, because *afaik* `Object.finalize()` is not garuanteed to be called. I would like to avoid that the user needs to call a `free()` method. Also, the library would be used in an embeded system, that means some of the objects are owned by the application and some by the Java runtime. When the Java plugin saves a reference to memory that is owned by the application it may happen that the application has already freed it and therefore the reference is invalid.

Was that clear enough?

Thanks,

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412964/forcing-the-gc-to-collect-jni-proxy-objects

Comment: @Niklas please explain why you would like to avoid the user needing to call explicit disposal method. AFAIK there is no other reliable solution.

Comment: @PavelZdenek Because it's one of the benefits of a language with garbage collection to not care for memory management. But if you say it is the only way.. :/

Comment: @Niklas well by embracing JNI, you voluntarily lost carefree GC :) For more info and some recommended reading about finalizers, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13046607/886653

Comment: Java can't automagically detect when native code has deallocated some chunk of native memory it doesn't manage. You need to give Java full control if you want to take advantage of its garbage collection facilities safely.

Comment: @SamuelAudet By *full control*, you mean to expose the memory management (freeing, allocation is usually done with the constructor) to the Java interface?

Comment: Yes, have the memory available to Java as long as it can be used by Java. Obviously you could modify your native code to notify Java when it frees memory, but that requires modification to the existing library.

Comment: Depending on what you need to free, you must either give control to Java via JNI as Samuel already pointed out or call free() on JNI_OnUnload().